# SharpSnmp: get OID or MIB from simulator agent

Tags: c#, snmp, sharp-snmp

How is it possible to get OID or MIB from agent, started like shown in snmpd sample?

---

I'm just starting to learn `snmp`. At first, the learning plan is to create any agent simulator and a simple client to query some information from agent.

After downloading and slightly exploring `snmpd` sample, I, probably, succeded with using [SharpSnmpLib.Engine](https://github.com/lextudio/sharpsnmplib-samples/tree/master/SharpSnmpLib.Engine) to create a "hello world" agent. It seems to be listening for incoming requests.

But, now I struggle with how to create a client, which would get any info from this agent. To be more specific, how could I get OID or MIB from the newly made agent, so that it's possible to send requests to it?

---

`snmpd` uses [SharpSnmpLib.Engine](https://github.com/lextudio/sharpsnmplib-samples/tree/master/SharpSnmpLib.Engine). My code is same as here:

[sharpsnmplib-samples/Samples/CSharpCore/snmpd/Program.cs](https://github.com/lextudio/sharpsnmplib-samples/blob/master/Samples/CSharpCore/snmpd/Program.cs)

Thanks!

Comment: For that sample project, you know the OIDs from the source code, https://github.com/lextudio/sharpsnmplib-samples/blob/master/Samples/CSharpCore/snmpd/Program.cs#L30 For a real world SNMP agent, you need to refer to documentation of its vendor, and the agent capabilities, https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.halu101/cap.htm

Comment: @LexLi, Thanks a lot! Here is one of the constructors of objects put into the ObjectStore: `public SysDescr() : base(new ObjectIdentifier("1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0")) {...`